# Are there any best practices for optimizing computations?

Tags: contract-design, gas, optimization

As complex computations cost a lot of gas (sometimes more than actually forecasted), so are there any popular ways or techniques where I can optimize a complex computation to a simplified version of the same, for saving on the gas costs?

Comment: I'm taking this question to be about optimising computation *on the chain*, which is a good and useful thing to consider, although different from the *off-chain* technique I describe [here](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/68/25).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the high cost of blockchain-based computation, it is definitely worthwhile to performance optimise the computations performed in the chain itself.  One basic technique used by almost all developers of blockchain-based applications is to **develop applications in a testing environment** where the gas cost of using the application can be repeatedly measured without deploying to the public Ethereum blockchain and incurring an actual cost in terms of ether.  Once the application has reduced gas needs to reasonable levels, then it can be deployed in the wild!

It's also important to **use the appropriate opcodes/pseudocontracts for frequently re-used operations** such as calculating of hashes or verifying of signatures.  The gas costs of these methods are substantially lower than implementing the operation yourself within the scripting language of the Ethereum Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few techniques which can be used depending on what you're optimizing for:

- Deploy [libraries](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries)
- Enable [compiler optimizations](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#internals-the-optimizer)
- Network-specific [tips & tricks](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html#tips-and-tricks)

Some contracts are [pre-compiled](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous.html?highlight=ecrecover#global-variables), allowing for quick access in Solidity to otherwise complex functions such as ECRECOVER, RIPEMD160, SHA256.