# What's the conditions of mining if someone has the most powerfull device in network?

Tags: mining

If in ethereum network a miner has a device with 10 power(for example) and another one has a device with 5 power. Is person 1 get the mining reward for ever? Or is it possible to person 2 mine some blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the current Ethereum protocol, which uses proof of work to secure the network.

Statistically, the miner with 10 units of computation will mine 2/3 of the blocks on the network and the miner with 5 units of computation will get 1/3. I.e., a miner with x% of the computing power of the network will statistically mine x% of blocks.

"The most powerful device" != majority (e.g. eight users with one unit of computing power and one with two units -- the most powerful device is only 20% of the network). A miner with a majority (i.e., more than 50%) of computing power can do things like [roll back transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/542/during-a-51-attack-what-can-the-attacker-actually-accomplish), however. Also, such a miner, if acting *maliciously*, can ignore the work being done by the minority miners and thus obtain 100% of the rewards.

Answer (score 3):

**in short**:the mining(POW) is a probabilistic process so in your example the first has a probability of P=2/3 and the second has a p=1/3. in other term the second can get a reward but with a low probability.