# Is it possible to use a modifier so that certain functions can only be executed by the contract, itself?

Tags: contract-development, modifiers

How can you program a contract so certain functions can only be called by other functions within the contract? Would you use a modifier? In the example below I'd want a user to have to call `metaAwesomeness()` to access `awesomeness()`, which would otherwise be inaccessible via `superDuperOnly()`:

```
contract superDuper {
    modifier superDuperOnly() {if (msg.sender != address(this)) throw; _};    
    function awesomeness() superDuperOnly {};
    function metaAwesomeness() {awesomeness()};
}
```

Taking it one step further, I'd also be interested to use this modifier on another contract, so only `superDuper` functions can call `kindaCool`'s `nifty()`:

```
import "./superDuper.sol";
contract kindaCool {
    function nifty() superDuperOnly {};
}
```

---

EDIT: for solution (Pt 1):

The first contract, `superDuper`, would look like:

```
contract superDuper {   
    function awesomeness() internal {};
    function metaAwesomeness() {awesomeness()};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing something really weird, you can limit functions to their own contract by simply marking them `private`.

If you want to limit functions in your contract to another contract, you're on the right track, but you need to manage the address of the particular instance of that contract that you're interested in and check that against `msg.sender` in your modifier.

Comment: To limit the function to your contract and its children, use `internal`.

Comment: Ah, yes. `internal` seems to be the best way to limit contract functions as intended above. [Reference.](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/634/4186)