# storage and memory error

Tags: solidity, remix

I am trying to execute the following example listed in the documentation using solidity 0.4

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract C {
    uint[] data1;
    uint[] data2;

    function appendOne() {
        append(data1);
    }

    function appendTwo() {
        append(data2);
    }

    function append(uint[] storage d) {
        d.push(1);
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Error: Location has to be memory for publicly visible functions (remove the "storage" keyword).

When I remove the storage keyword I get another error:

> Error: Member "push" is not available in uint256[] memory outside of storage.
>               d.push(1);

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use [internal](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/631/use-of-internal-key-word-in-a-function-definition-within-a-solidity-contract) or private modifier :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract C {
    uint[] data1;
    uint[] data2;

    function appendOne() {
        append(data1);
    }

    function appendTwo() {
        append(data2);
    }

    function append(uint[] storage d) internal{
        d.push(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: the function parameters are in the storage or in memory?

Comment: **state variables are always in storage
**local variables always reference storage
**parameters (also return) of functions: memory

Comment: Why does using internal help?