# Yellow flags, simple replacement?

Tags: solidity, warnings

Can anyone give me a straight answer, (not trained stranded in no man lands) do I just change the words from (functions to Constructor) yellow warnings below.

```
browser/ballot.sol:77:5: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
    function Owned() public {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

browser/ballot.sol:118:5: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
    function ?name?Token() public {
    ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).

browser/ballot.sol:91:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);

        ^-----------------------------------^
browser/ballot.sol:152:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        ^------------------------------^
browser/ballot.sol:167:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ^-----------------------------------^
browser/ballot.sol:185:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        ^------------------------^
browser/ballot.sol:206:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ^-----------------------------------^
browser/ballot.sol:224:9: Warning: Invoking events without "emit" prefix is deprecated.
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, tokens);
        ^--------------------------------------^
```

Comment: Achala, hello, I see that you edit the above warnings, are you stating that I can amend the yellow warnings? If so thank you. Anne, Blocker I will read your post, thank you.

Comment: All the warnings you have here are deprecated warnings, In short term it may not cause a problem, but in a long run you may need to think about seriously. However it is always good to fix the warnings. Check [this quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-could-go-wrong-from-using-deprecated-or-obsolete-code-in-programming) as well.

Comment: Thank you, I sorted all yellows now I gone up to red!, I am now getting a red Parser Error: Expected token Semicolon got 'LParen' I worked in India since 2005, my IOC includes working in Indian, Nepal, and I hope Sri Lanka.

Comment: so the error is linked to Constructor Owed () public {owner = msg.sender:}

Comment: hi, thank you, it worked I now have another red Parser Error, just seeing if I can work it out, Anne,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
function Owned() public {
    //....
}
```

to

```
constructor() public {
    /...
}
```

**And**

Change all

`Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);` to `emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);`

and

`Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);` to `emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);`

As I mentioned in the comments, all the warnings you have here are deprecated warnings, However it is always good to fix the warnings. So just do the above changes. Check [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/28537/16301) for more on warnings.

Comment: Manage to fix red Parsen, have more warnings so giving up for today! Thank you many need help tomorrow! Anne,