# Access and call an internal function through another contract

Tags: solidity

Someone asked about the `internal` visibility function in solidity.

Two comments claimed that despite being internal at the access and code level, there would be some ways to be able to access and call a function marked `internal` from another contract.

- the first comment says that through the "deposit challenge verify" mechanism it is possible to get around this
- the second says that through upcode `EXTCODECOPY` is also possible.

The post: ['internal' keyword in a function definition in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/631/internal-keyword-in-a-function-definition-in-solidity)

I don't know if I'm getting confused or if they actually said that it's possible to access and call from outside the contract a function marked `internal`. I've studied and read several things and I haven't seen how this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

So in general *internal* is something that can only be accessed via the contract and derived contracts, but let's get into those instances.

The *deposit-challenge-verify* mechanism is defining the codebase off-chain then use group consensus (i.e. a workaround).

The *EXTCODECOPY* method as described in the code retrieves the byte code for the entire contract and then it's your jobs to do what you need.
https://github.com/0xsequence/sstore2/blob/master/contracts/utils/Bytecode.sol

Comment: I loved your comment, it was the best so far. So is it really possible to call an internal function from outside the contract through these actions? If you can clarify more about ``EXTCODCOPY`` I would be very grateful. It retrieves the byte code, but even in that retrieval I don't understand how it will be able to call and interact with an internal function that forbids it to call.